# Rotation for UISplitView in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

I have implemented `SplitView` in my app.

My app is for both ios 5 and ios 6.

In ios 5 using method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

the rotation works fine.

But in ios 6 the roataion methods do not call. I have tried following methods for ios 6 ;

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

I have also searched and tried other methods of rotation for ios 6 , but they didn't work.

I want to support rotation both for ios 5 and ios 6.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you turn ON all the Supported Orientation in Summary tab of Targets Navigator??

Comment: The rotation doesn't work, or your methods don't get called?

Comment: @hpiOSCoder - yes , i have turned ON for all supported orientation

Comment: @jrturton - methods don't get called.

Comment: So what do you want to do in those methods? If the interface is rotating correctly already?

Comment: @jrturton I want to rotate the views as per device rotation. Because now views are not rotated as per device rotation.

Comment: Ok, sorry, we confused each other there. I get you now. How are you creating your interface, storyboard, xib, code? Is your split view controller the window's root view controller?

Comment: @jrturton - i am creating interface using code. and yes my split view controller is the window's root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please override this method in AppDelegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;//Or Required by
}
```